# get console.log's color output as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

In nodejs, when we run `console.log({a: 3})`, we get a nice colored output, with the `3` being colored brown.

How can we get the raw colored output of console.log to stdout?

```js
let output = getConsoleLogOutput({a: 3});
// output is now '{ a: \x1B[33m3\x1B[39m }'

console.log(output);
console.log({a: 3});
// both console logs should print the same in the terminal
```

For the context of why I need such a function, I want to setup a local browser nodejs terminal where the output of `eval` is sent to the browser, and displayed in `xterm.js`, while retaining the coloring of `console.log`.

Comment: That, uh, that sounds like a huge security liability? How are you going to lock down the `fs`, `child_process` etc. APIs?

Comment: Yes, if it were to be exposed out to the web, but since this is only accessible locally, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a `getConsoleLogOutput` function - your "nodejs terminal" would just take the stdout of the node process, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `colors` option to [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) that node's `console.log` uses internally:

> `colors` `<boolean>` If `true`, the output is styled with ANSI color codes. Colors are customizable. See [Customizing `util.inspect` colors](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_customizing_util_inspect_colors). Default: `false`.

Or maybe you just want to [instantiate](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_new_console_stdout_stderr_ignoreerrors) your own [`Console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_class_console), which offers an option for this as well:

> `colorMode` `<boolean> | <string>` Set color support for this `Console` instance. Setting to `true` enables coloring while inspecting values. Setting to `false` disables coloring while inspecting values. Setting to `'auto'` makes color support depend on the value of the `isTTY` property and the value returned by `getColorDepth()` on the respective stream. This option can not be used, if `inspectOptions.colors` is set as well. Default: `'auto'`.